# flutter webview_flutter plugin wont work because of gradle problem?

Tags: gradle, webview, dart, flutter

gradle error when adding flutter webview plugin to flutter project

Hi , Im developing an app with flutter , and it is working until i add
flutter webview plugin to it , and then i get this error :

```
* Error running Gradle:
ProcessException: Process "C:\Users\p.mikaeil\Desktop\Files\Flutter Project\newapp\android\gradlew.bat" exited abnormally:
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
* What went wrong:
A problem occurred configuring root project 'android'.
> Could not resolve all artifacts for configuration ':classpath'.
   > Could not find com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.10.2.
     Searched in the following locations:
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.10.2/gradle-4.10.2.pom
       - https://dl.google.com/dl/android/maven2/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.10.2/gradle-4.10.2.jar
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.10.2/gradle-4.10.2.pom
       - https://jcenter.bintray.com/com/android/tools/build/gradle/4.10.2/gradle-4.10.2.jar
     Required by:
```

i tried changing the gradle version in android folder but did'nt solve the problem.

how can i fix this problem ? 
thanks to any suggestions .

Comment: your flutter version number?

Comment: @user1462442 1.0.0

Comment: The gradle seems a bit too new. I think you should use a lower webview version until the rest of flutter catches up. webview is alpha software and going through tons of churn

Comment: @user1462442  I Changed the gradle to version 3.2.1 and same thing happened

Comment: I mean changing the webview_flutter package versions

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After searching and testing alot , i find the problem solution  :;

The problem was because my repositories not working .

Before Fixing the problem , my Project Build.gradle was like this :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

And After fixing the problem Project Build.gradle Should be like this :

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.lint/lint-gradle-api'
        }
    }

    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.2.1'
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        maven {
            url 'https://maven.google.com/'
            name 'Google'
        }
        jcenter()
        maven {
            url 'https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.android.tools.lint/lint-gradle-api'
        }
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Also I Changed The Compile Sdk Version and Target Sdk Version in android app build.gradle to 28 .

And You should also check your plugin versions for compatibility to android x .

Thanks to this greate community .

Comment: Yea. I was imagining a gradle mismatched. Flutter does not change sdk version fast enough and webview is just alpha software. I am not sure where because gradle tends to break in 2 to 4 places at once. Good job on fixing your problem.

Comment: You are a life saver