# problem when build a Gradle (Could not create task ':path_provider_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'). in flutter for android

Tags: android, flutter, gradle

every time I want to build the android project in flutter shows this message:

```
Could not create task ':path_provider_android:generateDebugUnitTestConfig'.
this and base files have different roots: E:\apps\our_class\build\path_provider_android and F:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\path_provider_android-2.0.9\android.
```

I tried many versions of Gradel, but still same problem

Answer (score 14):

I have fixed this issue by moving my whole project to C: drive where i have installed the flutterSDK. I moved my project to C:\Users\name\AndroidStudioProjects

Comment: Any other way to fix this issue?

Comment: @FaizanMubasher Not found yet

Comment: I don't like moving my project but I should admit that it works perfectly

Answer (score 12):

This issue is a pain for me I normally fix this issue by doing the following steps

1. run flutter clean / delete the build folder
2. Build the project on Android studio
3. run flutter pub get

Answer (score 8):

You just needed to delete conflicting file from this location

> E:\apps\our_class\build\path_provider_android

Which could be done with

```
flutter clean
```

And then tried gradle build or sync again

Answer (score 5):

I was having the same issue. I only had to remove
`.flutter-plugins` and `.flutter-plugins-dependencies` from main project root (not android module not)

Answer (score 2):

It works fine when I change my gradle version in ***android/build.gradle***

**Before I change my gradle file it looks like**

```
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:7.2.2'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

**After I change it**

```
  dependencies {
    classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:4.1.0'
    classpath "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-gradle-plugin:$kotlin_version"
}
```

Then run `flutter clean` to clean the previous build file

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

You can move your project to the same drive as where your "pub-cache" is (like [Akshay's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70922913/17271785) stated)

But if you don't feel like to move your project around, you can move your pup-cache folder to your project's drive, then add an environment variable "PUB_CACHE" pointing to that folder directory.
(Detail information here: https://dart.dev/tools/pub/environment-variables)

In conclusion, just keep your project folder and pub-cache folder on the same "root" (or drive)

Answer (score 0):

i had same problem and this answer helped me. i hope it's work for you

https://stackoverflow.com/a/54596753/12315661

Comment: unfortunately , same issue

Answer (score 0):

run

```
flutter clean
```

without running

```
flutter pub get
```

Answer (score 0):

To address this issue gracefully, kindly adhere to the following refined steps for an optimal resolution:

1. ```
   Launch the terminal and navigate to the Android directory.
   ```
2. ```
   Execute the command: flutter clean
   ```
3. ```
   Implement the command: flutter pub cache repair
   ```
4. ```
     Invalidate and restart Android Studio to ensure seamless integration of the changes.
   ```

Answer (score 0):

the best solution is to move your project to the disk

> C:\Users\MainUserName\AndroidStudioProjects